# Assetic unable to find file

Tags: symfony, assetic

I am trying to link a css file (that lives in a bundle) inside a twig template :

```
{% stylesheets 
    '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The first error message I get is:

*You must add AcmeFooBundle to the assetic.bundle config...*

This is the config :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        []
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

Then I try to add AcmeFooBundle in the **bundles** directive but then I get an error:

*Unable to find file....*

I can't understand what I am doing wrong here...

Dumping the default configs of the assetic configuration in the console (using **php app/console config:dump-reference assetic** ) I can see AcmeFooBundle bundle listed in the **bundles** directive...

Answer (score 28):

Unless you need to whitelist some bundles for Assetic, just remove the `bundles` option from the config.

Comment: thank u elnur for you response. I tried to remove the **bundles** directive but still I get an, "unable to find..." error

Comment: add AcmeFooBundle to the config: bundles: [AcmeFooBundle] (but dont ask me why)

Answer (score 14):

The following works for me:

1. Create bundle e.g.:

   ```
   php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/Bundle/BlogBundle --no-interaction
   ```

   See: [Generating a New Bundle Skeleton](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html)
2. Add Assetic imports as the following:

   ```
   {% javascripts '@AcmeBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}
   ```
3. Add Bundle to assetic config:

   ```
   # Assetic Configuration
   assetic:
       ...
       bundles:        ['AcmeBlogBundle']
       ...
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and elnur's suggestion worked.  Here's my assetic config for your reference

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```