# How do I fix "Add myBundle to the asseticBundle config" symfony2 exception?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I am trying to use the TWIG `{% javascript %}` tag to link to my `.js` file it return me with the following exception :

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("You must add CompetitiongameBundle to the assetic.bundle config to use the {% javascripts %} tag in CompetitiongameBundle:game:index.html.twig.") in "CompetitiongameBundle:game:index.html.twig".
```

My `index.html.twig` looks like :

```
{% javascripts 'CompetitiongameBundle/Resources/views/public/js/*'%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}" ></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
Hello {{ name }}!

<a href='{{ nexturl }}' >Login</a>
```

My Bundle is already present in the config file when I do :

```
php app/console config:dump-reference assetic
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Check this question and the two proposed solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376946/assetic-unable-to-find-file

Comment: It would be goo id you actually select an answer to this question.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Yes I tried and it solved the issue for me. For someone (like me) who doesn't know initially how to add then just:

1. edit `app/config/config.yml`
2. then go to `assetic:`
3. under assetic: go to `bundles: []`
4. and in `bundles: []` //type your bundle name

for instance if your bundle is **`Acme\DemoBundle`**, then do the following

```
assetic:
   bundles: [ AcmeDemoBundle ]
```

No quotes around `AcmeDemoBundle`. That's it. (Symfony2)

Comment: If needed, additional bundles should be separated by commas.

Comment: I'm using symfony2.3, I added my bundle to the array but I still have the same exception. Even when I comment the bundles I get the same exception message. What should I do?

Comment: If you are migrating to prod, and have this issue, don't forget to clean your cache and dump your assetic assets : " php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug " and " php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug "

Comment: @Dev DOS do u found a solution .. ?

Answer (score 24):

If you want assetic to include your bundles by default, you can comment (with #) the line `bundles: []`

ex:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: are there any side effect for commenting bundles?

Comment: None that I can think of. It just makes assetic include all bundles in your project. Maybe it can slow down your app, but personally I never noticed any differences in speed.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes you need to make decisions on the fly, then you can use use [DependencyInjection](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/index.html).

For example to [loads and manages configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html):

```
<?php

namespace You\ExampeBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/* ... */

class YouExampeExtension extends Extension
{

    /* ... */

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /* ... */

        $aAsseticBundle = $container->getParameter('assetic.bundles');
        $aAsseticBundle[] = 'YouExampeBundle';
        $aAsseticBundle[] = 'AnotheBundle';
        $container->setParameter('assetic.bundles', $aAsseticBundle);

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You can use more complex logic to manipulate the configuration(in reasonable limits)

Comment: This is particularly useful if you extend another Bundle using Bundle inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your bundle to bundle: [] row of assetic: section in app/config/config.yml file (symfony 2.1)